# android emulator error Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE] when installing gms

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator

i am trying to install com.google.android.gms.apk to my emulator to try  a project on Android Maps. But i get an error Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE] . I tried to uninstall the package, but it shows failure.

Comment: Please post your manifest.

Comment: Which failure does it show when uninstalling? The same?

Answer (score 1):

1) Start you emulator and check 'wipe user data'

2) run adb -e install com.google.android.gms.apk from terminal

Answer (score -1):

You can't run google map on an emulator. You have to test it on a real device.

The only thing you can do is getting a mock location via LocationManager to show it's coordinates.